# Soft Indicating Vowels

Tags: произношение

Sometimes I find it hard to pronounce letter combinations with `л` such as `лю` at the end of the word `люблю` (or perhaps `ля`), and it's hard to tell whether or not native speakers are saying 'lyu' or just 'lu'. Is there any secret (other than softening the `л`) to saying these combos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to pronunciation, "лю" in *люблю* is like "lu" in *illusion* if you say it energetically with your lips rounded and protruded. Basically, it's the soft / л / plus an / у / that you say in the front part of your mouth instead of the back part as you'd usually do for аn / у / used in combination with hard consonants.

"Ля" in, for example, *Земля*, the Earth, is the soft / л / from "лю" plus an open vowel sound / æ / from, for example, *land* if you say it right in the front part of your mouth and without creating any constrictions to the airflow; try smiling with the corners of your mouth and also relaxing and "dropping" your jaw a bit for better effect.